# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and invalid identifier issues

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a function using types, it gives me two errors saying:
Error(12,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(27,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "UT": invalid identifier

I can't see any issues with my code as shown below, any help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE FUNCTION ESF_GET_USERS
          
RETURN tc_users
IS
    l_users       tc_users;           

BEGIN   
      SELECT t_user
        (  
            Uname,
            FName,
            Sname,
            PName,
            Tit,
            mail,
            FC,
            SC,
            SN,
            SD,
            RC,
            RN,
            CC || ' ' || CN,
            UT
        )
        BULK COLLECT INTO l_users
        FROM USERS_MV;

    RETURN l_users;

EXCEPTION   
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'No records returned');     
END esf_users;
```

I am creating two types, one is an object and the second is a table from that object as shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE T_USER 
AS OBJECT
(  
    UNAME       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    FNAME       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
    SNAME         VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
    PNAME   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
    TIT           VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
    MAIL           VARCHAR2(24 BYTE),
    FC     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    SC      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    SN      VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    SD       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    RC   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    RN   VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    HN  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    UT  VARCHAR2(7 BYTE)
);



CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE TC_USERS AS TABLE OF t_user;
```

The Materialized view code is:

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "USERS_MV" 
  AS select "UName",
"FName",
"Sname",
"PName",
"Tit",
"mail",
"FC",
"SC",
"SN",
"SD",
"RC",
"RN",
"CC",
"CN",
"UT"
 from (
 SELECT ...
```

Comment: whats with the double-quote on line 1?

Comment: sorry, its just a typo while copying and pasting

Comment: Can you post `users_mv` ddl?

Comment: @Kumar I have added the mv code, it is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a classic mistake in Oracle - never enclose anything into double quotes. If you do it once (at the time of creation of that object), you have to do it always.

```
SQL> create table test ("Id" number);

Table created.

SQL> select id from test;
select id from test
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier


SQL> select ID from test;
select ID from test
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier


SQL> select "ID" from test;
select "ID" from test
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier


SQL> select "Id" from test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

I suggest you recreate everything - remove double quotes. Oracle will store names using UPPPERCASE, but you can reference objects/columns using any case you want.